# What causes this corkscrew-shaped object to rise up in a stream of water falling down?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics, coriolis-effect

A corkscrew-shaped object is floating in a tub of water. When water is poured into the tub from some height, the object starts rising up vertically in the stream of water. The water stream is falling down in a spiral fashion. What is the Physics behind this? Is it the turning effect on the object caused by the spiral motion of the water falling on it? Or is it some other phenomenon?

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Piece of fishing monofilament attached to the bucket.

Comment: Tamil [James Randi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Randi); find the video and focus on the *top* of the stick *pulling* the rest, at a roughly constant distance from the point where the water triangle switches to a roughly tubular stream; the point is uplifting  like the top of the stick.

Comment: apologies...I didn't quite understand. I watched the video number of times. are you suggesting there is a stick pulling the object. Is there a filament attached to the object, causing us to believe the object is rising ?

Comment: I'm affirming the above filament assertion, detailing the behavior of the object.  It is sleight of hand with no interesting physics aspects.

Comment: I'm afraid you people are mistaken, and frankly surprised at the lack of curiosity: https://youtube.com/shorts/-_LmcIaPMAQ?feature=share

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos No filament or string is needed as Abdul Moiz Qureshi link. Obviously no tricks. It seems that water is trying to get past the helix. So the force may be coming from the dissipated energy and momentum of the water. It may even be acting as a reverse Archimedes screw.

Comment: @Duke You may investigate the deleted videos and consider comoving particles in a long, stable, matter stream, where the gadget starts out stationary. The video is designed to mislead.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos This video https://youtube.com/shorts/-_LmcIaPMAQ?feature=share is no trick. It is Archimedes' screw on reverse water flow that causes the screw to rise. This is possible by reducing a little bit of momentum from the water.

Comment: This is ***not***  the video I refer to! You evidently did not access the deleted videos, where the chicanery was more obvious! You appear to misunderstand Archimedes' screw!

Answer (score 2):

This really seems to be a fake, although there are not enough details given to  be 100% certain.  The simple intuition they are playing with is strong...if the stick is moving with the fluid, there is no relative motion of the stick to the fluid and therefore no way for it to extract energy from the flow and begin to move through the fluid.  Viscous fluid is dissipative, so any initial relative motion would decay.  Exotic situations could change this if there are strong velocity gradients in the fluid flow field, but it would take a strange helical flow field to have a chance to induce the observed motions, and there is no indication this flow has the necessary gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to when a paddle wheel boat is places in the river and the wheel is not locked. The paddle wheel turns backwards as the river current pushes the wheel in turn making the boat go against current.

Comment: In the inertial frame of the current, the boat is floating still, and the wheel is not turning: it is virtually sitting still on a lake. Now push it forward from the outside. The wheel will turn, but it will not be propelling the boat!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if the corkscrew is hollow then the water flow eventually takes the path of least resistance through the verticle axis centre of the corkscrew & the buoyancy of the corkscrew overcomes the deflected downward pressure of the water (swapping down force for kinetic horizontal force as its spins round a high pressure downward force in the centre) to make the lighter than water corkscrew rise up in the (now) marginal down current body of water on the outside of the high pressure centre stream..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

It is simple 1st grade physics people! I am really surprised how few seem to be familiar with this-was shown it by physics teacher many years ago in 1st year physics class.
The shape causes it to act like a propellor when flowing water causes it to spin. Faster the flow faster the spin.